# date-fns lib problem. addMonths method. February problem

Tags: javascript, date, date-fns

My code:

```
import { addMonths } from 'date-fns';
addMonths(startDate, frequencyValue);
```

At the moment it adds like:

- December **30** (our start date)
- January 30
- February 28
- March **28**
- April **28**

And I need:

- January **30**
- February 28
- March **30**
- April **30**
- etc.

is there any solution?

I did not find any parameters in the doc that could suggest a solution.

Comment: Do you need to add the months one at a time? Can't you just add 1, 2, or more months from the original start date?